# ¿Como unir JTextField con JButton?

Tags: java, netbeans

Quiero darle un mejor estilo a mi programa y quiero unir el boton con la caja de texto pero no lo logro hacer. Quiero que se vea así.

[image: Así quiero que se vea]

Y yo solo logro que se vea así.

[image: Así se me ve]

El mio lo estoy haciendo directamente con netbeans, el otro esta hecho con codigo directamente...

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo de lo que intentaste hacer o como lo tienes actualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende del `layout` que estés usando. Tal cual tienes la ventana, un `FlowLayout` puede ser adecuado. `FlowLayout` tiene un constructor en el que puedes pasar como parámetros el espacio entre componentes en horizontal (hgap) y de los componentes con el borde inferior/superior (vgap).

Adicionalmente, tiene métodos `setHgap()` y `setvgap()` para fijar esos espacios.